# Use Redmine Wiki, project independent

Tags: redmine, wiki, redmine-plugins

I'm searching for the opportunity to use the existing wiki in Redmine project independent.

**Why project independent?** 
I need it for general topics and plugins which are not part from a project.

Or exists a plugin which I can use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People generally create a "General" project or something similar for the global stuff.

Everything in Redmine is part of a project. There are no global areas with user-acccessible data. This is by design, is leveraged by the permissions system and other areas and is not about to change.

Comment: but can I show all projects wiki on one page so I can find or analysis wiki pages in a better way?